# How to reference multiple rows every nth row?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a set of data in column A1 to A100. In column B, I would like to reference three rows from column A while skipping every other two rows, like this:

```
Column A
1
2
3
4
5
6
...
100

Column B
3
4
5
8
9
10
...
```

How do I do that? I can use the offset function to skip every nth row, but I can only make it display one row at a time, when I actually want three rows at a time.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 8 times.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently want to skip rows `1,2`, `6,7`, `11,12`, `16,17`, `21,22` and so on. Chances are that the *data* in these rows differs somehow from the data in the rest of the rows, and the easiest solution would probably be to filter by that *data* rather than blindly filtering by row numbers.

Nevertheless, here is a formula that filters by row numbers the way you describe:

`=filter(A1:A, regexmatch(trim(mod(row(A1:A), 5)), "3|4|0"))`

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [regexmatch()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292). To learn the exact [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Here are a couple additional patterns to choose which rows to show.

Only show rows 5, 10, 15 and 77:

`=filter(A1:A, regexmatch(trim(row(A1:A)), "^(5|10|15|77)$"))`

Show all rows *except* rows 5, 10, 15 and 77:

`=filter(A1:A, not(regexmatch(trim(row(A1:A)), "^(5|10|15|77)$")))`

Only show rows with odd row numbers 1, 3, 5, 7...:

`=filter(A1:A, isodd(row(A1:A)))`

Only show rows with even row numbers 2, 4, 6, 8...:

`=filter(A1:A, iseven(row(A1:A)))`

Show every third row starting from row `2`:

`=filter(A1:A, (row(A1:A) - 2) / 3 = int((row(A1:A) - 2) / 3))`

Show rows `4,5`, `9,10`, `14,15`, `19,20`, `24,25...`:

```
=filter(A1:A, 
  ((row(A1:A) - 4) / 5 = int((row(A1:A) - 4) / 5)) 
  + 
  ((row(A1:A) - 5) / 5 = int((row(A1:A) - 5) / 5)) 
)
```